# Euro External Outboard Bottom Bracket - Heard a crack while installing

Tags: bottom-bracket, bsa

While installing a euro bottom bracket (BSA threaded), I heard a crack while tightening the NDS. The frame is aluminum and I'm not sure what the material of the bottom bracket is.

[Bottom bracket](https://www.profileracing.com/product/euro-externaloutboard-bottom-bracket/)

[Frame](https://nsbikes.com/majesty,111,pl.html)

After I heard the crack, I unthreaded and it was slightly gritty towards the end, but still threaded and unthreaded from the frame fine. It appears that I'm able to get up to a certain torque before it cracks again.

Before I get flamed, I'd like to defend myself in saying that it was not cross threaded, and the torque wasn't ridiculous. The drive side was in fact torqued harder than the non drive side, so I figured it would be fine.

How much did that damage the threads? Since it's still holding *some* torque, am I fine to ride the bike? If I took it to a shop, would they be able to simply retap the thread? Should I order a new bottom bracket cup if they retap the thread?

Comment: Is this not a steel frame? Does anything have visible damage?

Comment: Also were the threads well lubricated and what with?

Comment: @NathanKnutson It was an aluminum frame. The threads were lubricated with Park Tool PPL-1 (essentially marine grease).